# How can I see ICMP error messages in response to UDP messages in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking, traceroute, recvmsg

I am trying to build a kind of traceroute in Ruby. The principle is that I send a UDP message with a TTL of 1 to the desired destination and get an ICMP error message back from the first hop. Since I do not want to use root privileges or similar for the program, I would like to use the native receive function.

I have therefore drafted the following code:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
# sharable_constant_value: literal

require 'socket'

sock = Socket.open(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, Socket::IPPROTO_UDP)

# Set TTL to one
sock.setsockopt Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_TTL, 1

# Enable receiving errors
sock.setsockopt Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_RECVERR, 1
sock.setsockopt Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_RECVTTL, 1

# Sending a packet to 1.1.1.1
dest = Socket.sockaddr_in 33435, '1.1.1.1'
sock.send "Test", 0, dest

# Receive error message
pp sock.recvmsg nil, Socket::MSG_ERRQUEUE
# Blocking forever
# But seeing ICMP error message in capture
```

or for IPv6:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
# sharable_constant_value: literal

require 'socket'

sock = Socket.open(Socket::AF_INET6, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, Socket::IPPROTO_UDP)

# Set IPv6 TTL / Hop Limit to 1
sock.setsockopt Socket::IPPROTO_IPV6, Socket::IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS, 1

dest = Socket.sockaddr_in 33435, '2a00:1450:4001:806::2003'
pp sock.send "Test", 0, dest
pp sock.recvmsg nil, Socket::MSG_ERRQUEUE
```

The problem I have now, however, is that `sock.recvmsg` (for IPv4 and IPv6) blocks forever and does not return an error message. However, according to the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#method-i-recvmsg), this should be the case (in my understanding). In WireShark I could see that the ICMP error messages also arrive as desired.
My question is therefore, how can I view the ICMP error message in Ruby?

Comment: UDP -> ICMP is one "ping" method used for traceroute, but you can also ICMP -> ICMP with a raw socket, which I think is more common. If I recall correctly, Windows `tracert` is one of the few implementations that uses UDP.

Comment: @tadman That's right. However, it requires root or cap_net_raw permission. Furthermore, the UDP method is used by default by the [inetutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/traceroute-invocation.html)/[iputils](https://github.com/iputils/iputils) and [scamper](https://www.caida.org/catalog/software/scamper/) implementation of traceroute.

Comment: I think you cannot do it like that, unless you specify the size of the message you want to receive. You are using a blocking call after all. You have to tell it what it should expect (the size). For example, if you try this:  `pp sock.recvmsg(1, Socket::MSG_ERRQUEUE, 1)`, you will see it DOES receive data.

Comment: `pp sock.recvmsg(1000, Socket::MSG_ERRQUEUE, 1000)` seems to print the whole message.

Comment: @Casper Thank you! This works perfectly for IPv4, but unfortunately not for IPv6.

Comment: I could imagine that this is due to the missing Socket::IPV6_RECVERR flag, but unfortunately this does not seem to be implemented in Ruby (I [reported](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/20258) this to ruby).

Comment: You can dig up the IPV6_RECVERR definition with Google. It's just a number, then you can input it manually. Quick lookup seems to indicate it should be integer 25.

Comment: @Casper Thank you! You're right. However, it is somehow nicer from the programming style to use constants. I have also opened a corresponding [PR](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/9930). If you post your answer, I can gladly accept it!